# How to Enable/Disable doublewrite buffer in mysql?

Tags: mysql, innodb

How do I enable/disable doublewrite buffer in mysql?

How to check if doublewrite buffer is enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 5):

There's a server variable with similar name, [`innodb_doublewrite`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_doublewrite) which can be used to check if this writing method is enabled:

```
mysql> select @@innodb_doublewrite;
+----------------------+
| @@innodb_doublewrite |
+----------------------+
|                    1 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.15 sec)
```

To set the corresponding mode, use either `--innodb-doublewrite` parameter for server start (CLI) or `innodb_doublewrite` configuration file directive.

Answer (score 0):

In a standard InnoDB / XtraDB installation, the doublewrite buffer is located in the main tablespace (whether you activate the innodb_file_per_table or not) and you have no option to control anything about it.

The feature adds an option (innodb_doublewrite_file) to have a dedicated location for the doublewrite buffer.